# Embedding an image in Flash Starling AS3 app

Tags: flash, starling-framework

I am just learning Starling, trying to put an image on the canvas.

the code I am looking at looks like this:

```
[Embed(source="wordvillelogo.png")]
public static const Mushroom:Class;
```

The image itself in located in the same directory as my .as files and FLA file.

Yet, when I compile the code I get an error

```
unable to resolve 'wordvillelogo.png' for transcoding
```

What is the correct format to embed this image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a '/' before you're path and it works... ?

http://karlvansanten.blogspot.nl/2009/04/unable-to-resolve-for-transcoding.html

Answer (score 1):

if Piterwilson`s answer is not true, try this:

```
[Embed(source="./wordvillelogo.png")]
public static const Mushroom:Class;
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use Embed to manage assets if you are targeting mobile. Embed is really slow and could hurt performance specially on the iPad 1 and some older android devices.

You should create an assets folder, embed it with your app and use starling's [AssetManager](http://wiki.starling-framework.org/manual/asset_management) class to get your assets. That's the fastest way, you already get your image as a texture so you don't have to create bitmapdata objects, passing them to a new texture, etc.